# Rails 3 nested model form creates duplicate model objects

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I've followed along with Ryan Bates' tutorial ([Episode 196 - Nested Model Forms (Revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised)) to create a form for a model (`Employee`) with a nested `has_many :through` model (`Capability`). For the most part it works; however, when I click the link to add a new model object to the form, *two* are created and inserted. I don't know why - I've struggled with this for a few evenings now and just can't work it out. Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong?

(`Capability` here represents a `has_many through` association: `Employee has_many :roles, through: :capabilities`).

#### form partial

```
<%= form_for(@employee) do |f| %>

  # Employee fields here ...

  <%= f.fields_for :capabilities do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'capability_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add capability", f, :capabilities %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

#### capability_fields partial

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.select :role_id, Role.all.collect{ |r| [r.name, r.id]} %>
  <%= f.check_box :primary_role_flag %>
  <%= f.text_field( :valid_from, :class => 'date') %>
  <%= f.text_field( :expires_on, :class => 'date') %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "Remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

#### link_to_add_fields application helper

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
  new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
  id = new_object.object_id
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
  end
  link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub('\n','&#xA')})
end
```

#### jQuery coffeescript

```
jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
    $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
    event.preventDefault()

  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem. I'll let you know If I come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

This may not help, but it looks like in my case the problem could be traced back to the [Decent Exposure](https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure) gem.

**Edit:** Okay, it looks like this was my fault and not Decent Exposure. I was explicitly setting the attributes using:

```
gallery.attributes = params[:gallery]
```

I do this because I need to check permissions before saving the record. Only it turns out Decent Exposure was already doing this for me. Thus, causing the duplication. I know this may not solve your problem, however all I had to do was remove that line from my controller and everything works fine.

I hope that at least gives you some ideas of what to look at.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I'm not using Decent Exposure, but it is possible that one of my plugins is duplicating this functionality. I'll keep this in mind if/when I come back to this feature. Thanks!